# Getting decimal values in valueformatter for showing decimal values on bar in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to show a bar grpah ([MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)) which has values in decimal.
but the graph shows them without decimal.
 My code for value formatter looks like this:

```
protected class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter{
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Initial value == "+value+" == "+entry.getVal());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Formatted value == "+df.format(value));
        return df.format((double)value);
    }
}
```

Following is the data used to draw the graph chart

```
"data":[[16003376.986129051,10003344],[25089516.75475807,20089516],[39517705.32395167,30517705],[2490973.063333333,3090973]]
```

Following is the value formatter log

```
Initial value == 1.6003376E7 == 1.6003376E7
Formatted value == 16003376
Initial value == 1.0003344E7 == 1.0003344E7
Formatted value == 10003344
Initial value == 1.6003376E7 == 1.6003376E7
Formatted value == 16003376
Initial value == 1.0003344E7 == 1.0003344E7
......many more
```

My concern is:

- The original value is converted from 16003376.986129051 to 1.6003376E7
- Graph shows value on top of the bar as 16003376, since decimal handling is not implemented yet
- How do i get the original value to convert it into 3 decimal figure since the decimal values are very important from financial point of view

[image: Bar Chart]

[image: Bar Chart with marker view]

Comment: show some images of your current chart

Comment: @cxphong Image of graph uploaded

Comment: This is not a problem with MPAndroidChart but with the way `DecimalFormat` works and the way [floating point numbers are represented and how to round them in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue ? I updated my answer with an examplee

Answer (score 0):

MPAndroidChart stores y-values inside an `Entry` as a `float`. As can be seen in [this commonly referenced article on floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), there are some numbers that cannot be accurately represented using floating points.

Instead of using the raw value of your parsed data as a `value` for your `Entry`, consider rounding the value to 3 decimal places **first**. This is a good idea anyway since we would like to maintain a separation of concerns between our model layer and our view layer and `Entry` is essentially part of the view layer. If you do this, your `ValueFormatter` will perform as expected.

So, when you are making the entries. Don't do this:

```
float rawX = rawDataSource.getFloat(0);
float rawY = rawDataSource.getFloat(1);
BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(rawX,rawY); //no!! need to round first
```

Do this instead:

```
float roundedX = (float) Math.round(rawDataSource.getFloat(0) * 100.0) / 100.0;
float roundedY = (float) Math.round(rawDataSource.getFloat(0) * 100.0) / 100.0;
BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(roundedX, roundedY);
```